# Asynchronous loading images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flickr, image-preloader

Is there a method for showing a loading image for dynamic images that are generated using Flickr? I have come across a way to do it as shown on the [Wacom Community](http://community.wacom.com) site but I have not been able to get it to work. Is there something simpler or does anyone have a better explanation than the originator of the technique from http://blog.realmofzod.com/asynchronous-image-loading-with-jquery/?

Answer (score 1):

I just got this working. YMMV:

```
<img src="images/blank.gif" onload="replaceImage(this, 'flickrthumbnailimageurl')"
width="75" height="75" />
```

And then `replaceImage`:

```
function replaceImage(img, replacementImage)
{
    img.onload = null;
    img.src = replacementImage;
}
```

blank.gif is just a 1x1 pixel solid gray image. Basically, the idea is that this blank image is loaded and expanded to 75x75 (to preserve layout). That almost immediately fires the onload handler, which changes the image's source to the desired image. It has the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

could do it with jquery:

```
<img src="http://myimages.com/loaderImage.jpg" id="imgIdLoading" />
<img src="http://flickr.com/image.jpg" id="imgId" style="display:none;" />

$('#imgId').load(function(){
    // ... loaded
    $('#imgIdLoading').remove();
    $('#imgId').show();  
}).error(function(){
    // ... not loaded
    $(this).attr('src','/whatever/error.png');
});
```